# Sci Fi Book about Humans and Robots fighting Rogue Robots

Tags: story-identification, books

This was a sci fi book I read in the late 90s. The overall story was about humans and robots under their control getting ready to fight off some rogue robots. I believe the main battle took place in an asteroid belt of some kind. The humans and their robots ultimately win.

I think what set this apart from most other sci fi battles is that the humans mostly were setting up missile defense platforms and that it wasn't really just space battleships blasting away at each other.

Not much to go on ultimately. But thank you in advance!

Comment: This seems a bit thin for an entire book.  Did the rest of plot lead up to this battle or follow on from it?  How were the "good" robots different from the "bad" robots?  Or was it just free will?  Why were the bad robots attacking anyway?

Comment: The plot leads up to the battle. It was free will. Unfortunately I don't recall the motivations of the bad robots. It was a different read from what I usually read, in that the spaceships were more platform like on the human side, and small sleek drone like craft from the rogue ai robot side.

Comment: It could be Fred Saberhagen's short story "Stone Place", part of his *Berserker* series of short stories and novels. It has a major battle in an asteroid belt against murderous machines. I don't recall any robots on the human side, but it has been decades since I read it.

Comment: Answered. That lead me to the exact book I was thinking of, which was Berserker Fury, published 1997. Not sure if Stone Place is included in that one, but, it did lead me to the cover art of the book which triggered my memory of it. Thank you! It really wasn't a lot to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Berserker Fury](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL656087M/Berserker_fury)* by Fred Saberhagen, published 1997, book 10 of his *Berserker* series. Klaus AE Mogensen really got the ball rolling.

> Berserkers: Relentless, remorseless, pity less, tireless, adaptive, cunning, self replicating, artificially intelligent, genocidal doomsday weapons of a long forgotten interstellar war between two extraterrestrial races known as the Builders (the Berserker creators) and their enemies the Red Race (both now extinct). Berserkers have only one programmed directive and purpose "Destroy all life." Ranging in size from approximately human (in the case of assassins and spies, which are rare) to minor asteroids (in the case of repair bases) they are typically large and roughly spherical space vessels. If one approaches your planet, MOVE OUT NOW!